# How do I insert bookmarks into a new PDF file using GhostXPS?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, xps

I want to convert XPS to PDF using [GhostXPS](http://www.ghostscript.com/GhostXPS.html). Using command line:

```
"S:\GhostXPS\gxpswin32-9.18.exe" @"S:\Temp\PS\XPS\TestXPSWrite.txt"
```

Where the options are in the TestXPSWrite.txt file:

```
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="S:\Temp\PS\XPS\TestMerged.pdf" 
-dNOPAUSE -dBatch 
"S:\Temp\PS\XPS\Test1.xps" 
"S:\Temp\PS\XPS\Test2.xps" 
"S:\Temp\PS\XPS\Test3.xps" 
"S:\Temp\PS\XPS\Bookmarks.txt"
```

Contents of Bookmarks.txt file:

```
[/Title (Summary) /Page 1 /OUT pdfmark
[/Title (TOC) /Page 2 /OUT pdfmark
[/Title (Chapter 1) /Page 3 /OUT pdfmark
```

Everything works fine except the Bookmarks.txt file which fails because it isn't an XPS file. If these were PostScript files using regular GhostScript exe then the bookmarks work fantastic. But not with XPS.

How do I insert bookmarks into a new PDF file using GhostXPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluntly, you can't.

The only way currently to add such content is, as you are aware, to use the pdfmark PostScript operator (that's what's in your bookmarks.txt file, its actually a PostScript program).

But since GhostXPS doesn't understand PostScript, you can't do that.

You could double process the file, passing the newly created PDF file back through Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device to get a second new PDF file and add the bookmarks during that stage. But double processing can cause odd things to happen with the content.

There may be a solution to this at a later date.

Comment: Can Ghostscript do XPS to PS? I might check that out then create the PDF from that for now.

Comment: Actually tried XPS > PS > PDF but just got garbage output.

Comment: I submitted a feature request at http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=696287

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: XPS->PS->PDF should work, but I was actually proposing XPS->PDF->PDF.Because the PDF interpreter uses PostScript, you can still process pdfmarks when the input is PDF. Because the PDF graphics model is richer than (level 2) PostScript you should get a better result. And if you are using an old version of Ghostscript you won't even be using ps2write to produce PostScript, which would be even worse.

Comment: OK I can try XPS->PDF->PDF. I'll just have to watch out for "odd things to happen" as you say. Our documents are fairly homogeneous so if it works it should be fine to use.

Comment: I tried it and everything looks fine (including the bookmarks) but still I get this error message on a certain page: "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly." So this is not good enough.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of Ghostscript and am no longer getting the error so we're good. But the XPS > PDF > PDF route takes longer. and has larger file size because it is bitmapping certain fonts.

Comment: Well, it will take longer, 2 conversions are slower than one, clearly. On the other hand, you get your bookmarks.... If the fonts are bitmapped then most likely there is some form of transparency and the whole page is being rendered. Can't say without seeing an example.